# How does Stack Overflow scale?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, hardware

How does Stack Overflow scale without any failures? What is its hardware configuration?

Comment: @Chacha102 You have 10887 rep; just edit it

Comment: I don't know if it's a duplicate, but [Which tools and technologies build the Stack Exchange Network?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/what-were-stack-overflow-server-fault-and-super-user-built-with) at least answers the second part

Comment: @Michael Can't I get the weekend off from editing things?

Answer (score 3):

For the Hardware / Sysadmin perspective you can find a lot of information about how things have been built out at http://blog.serverfault.com .

My biggest personal advice with scaling is that it is a cross-functional team based effort. For example, a lot of scaling is having good code, but you want also want good hardware and proper configurations, and a sound network architecture.